# ASP.NET custom control for short term memory

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I'm reasonably new to web programming, and I'm still struggling to get to grips with the fact that the server has a terrible short term memory, forgetting about what's on screen by the time you see it.

I'm currently trying to create a custom control that allows you to edit data fields inside a repeater. Depending on the format of the fields (The ElementFormat property), either a text box or a drop down list should be generated. Inside the markup of my page I have:

```
<custom:EditFieldControl ID="EditFieldControl" 
    runat="server" 
    ElementId='<%#Eval("Id")%>'                                                       
    ElementValue='<%#Eval("Value")%>' 
    ElementFormat='<%#Eval("Format")%>' 
    Visible="false" />
```

Control code-behind looks like this:

```
public class EditFieldControl : WebControl
{ 
    private TextBox textBox;
    private DropDownList dropDownList;    

    protected override void CreateChildControls()
    {
        switch (The Format of the field)
        {
            case "Text":
            {
                textBox = new TextBox
                {
                    Text = The existing value,
                    CssClass = "FieldTextBox"
                };
                this.Controls.Add(textBox);
                break;               
            }
            case "DropDownList":
            {
                dropDownList = new DropDownList
                {
                    //go get possible values from the database
                    CssClass = "FieldDropDown"
                };
                this.Controls.Add(dropDownList);
                break;
            }
            default:
                throw new ArgumentException("Invalid Format Type");
        }
        base.CreateChildControls();
    }

    public string Value
    {
        get
        {
            switch (ElementFormat)
            {
                case "DropDownList":
                    return dropDownList.SelectedValue;
                default:
                    return textBox.Text;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is, when a "save this field" button is clicked, the server looks for the EditFieldControl in that bit of the repeater, finds it, and then calls the value method, which promptly errors because it is trying to access either a text box or drop down list that no longer exist. My question is, how do I get at the value that the user has type in/selected? I presume I have to recreate the control earlier in the lifecycle, I'm just not sure when.

Comment: Dynamically created server controls must be recreated (usually in Page_Load) in order for their states to be repopulated and their 'true' values accessed.

Comment: @El: `Page_Load` is the worst place to do anything. `OnInit` is much better

Comment: And you usually need to re-do the data bindings. That's one of the bad parts of ViewState, and Asp.Net WebForms in general, and one of the main reasons people are migrating to MVC framework.

Comment: @abatishchev lol Ok. Yeah I've had problems with routines in `Page_Load`. Are there any particular reasons why `Page_Load` is so bad?

Comment: As recommended, I moved the code into the PageLoad event instead. Now the control is correctly constructed by the time the value needs to be looked up, and viewstate has magically retained all the values.

I tried putting the construction in Init, however the control properties have not been assigned at that point, and so the Format of the field is still null, hence an error was thrown.

Comment: @El: It's to do with the order the events are fired. OnLoad occurs after postback handling has occurred. This is pretty good explanation of page lifecycle events. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As recommended, I moved the code into the PageLoad event instead. Now the control is correctly constructed by the time the value needs to be looked up, and viewstate has magically retained all the values.

I tried putting the construction in Init, however the control properties have not been assigned at that point, and so the Format of the field is still null, hence an error was thrown.

Comment: This diagram is helpful: http://blog.krisvandermast.com/ASPNET20PageLifeCycle.aspx . Also this document: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The asp:Repeater is not an ideal control to edit data, it's more used to display. Suitable for editing are FormView, DetailsView and the best in your case is probably the ListView control. You can define separate templates for display (ItemTemplate), editing (EditItemTemplate) and Inserting (InsertItemTemplate). The Value property needs a setter to allow two-way binding. Use Bind instead of Eval.

Hope this helps.